# Is "for which" synonymous to "because of which"

Tags: grammar

> Those are the reasons **for which** they won't be here.
>
> Those are the reasons **because of which** they won't be here.

I am wondering if in this context the two means the same thing. What about other contexts? Are these two only equivalent in this particular sentence? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment by Jason Bassford -

> Neither sounds at all natural. Typically, it would be just *those are the reasons they won't be there*. Reasons normally *are*. (*What **is** the reason?*) You don't typically say that you do something because of a reason.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/84312)

Comment: @MatthewW: CW conversion of a comment to an answer is fine.